# How to request for data when I run on postman. At the moment the email, firstname and lastname are hardcoded to the code. How do I request the data?

Tags: node.js, mailchimp

I have hardcoded my data. How can I request the data to be entered when I request a post request on postman

```
const Mailchimp = require('mailchimp-api-v3');
const MailChimpConfig = require('./.env');
const axios = require('axios');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const mailchimp = new Mailchimp(MailChimpConfig.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY);

app.get('/api/memberList',(req, res) => {
  mailchimp.get(`/lists/${MailChimpConfig.MAILING_LIST_ID}/members`)
  .then(function(results){
    res.send(results);
  }).catch(function(err){
    res.send(err);
  });
});

app.post('/api/create', (req, res) => {

    //   const body = req.body;
    //   const { email, firstName, lastName } = body;
    let postData = {
        email_address: req.body.email_address,
        status: req.body.status,
        merge_fields: {
            FNAME: req.body.FNAME,
            LNAME: req.body.LNAME
        }
    }

       console.log(postData);
      // Make mailchimp API call 
      mailchimp.post(`/lists/${MailChimpConfig.MAILING_LIST_ID}/members`, postData)

        .then(function(results){
            res.send(results);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }); 
    });
const port = process.env.PORT || 9001;
app.listen(port);
console.log(`express app listening on port ${port}`);
```

My expected output should be entering data in postman. This created a member with the email firstnam and lastname I have hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send a json data in the request body. For example:

```
{
 "email": "test@mail.com",
 "firstName": "test",
 "lastName": "test",
}
```

In node you can get the data using:
File **server.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/create', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const body = req.body;
  const { email, firstName, lastName } = body;

  // Make mailchimp API call 
  mailchimp.post(`/lists/${MailChimpConfig.MAILING_LIST_ID}/members`, {
        email_address: email,
        status: 'subscribed',
        merge_fields: {
            FNAME: firstName,
            LNAME: lastName,
        }
    })
    .then(function(results){
        res.send(results);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }); 
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server running'));
```

If you want to reproduce the example use the following `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "nodeHelp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Put the `server.js` and the `package.json` in a folder and after that run:

> `npm install`
>
> `node server.js`

Comment: It doesn't work it says unexpected identifier for const body = req.body

Comment: how are you sending the data from postman? can you do a `console.log(req)`?

Comment: yes ``{
 "email_address": "spongebob@bob.com",
 "status": "subscribed",
 "merge_fields": {
  "FNAME": "Spongebob",
  "LNAME": "Squarepants"
 }
}```

Comment: Are you using `bodyParser`?

Comment: I am requesting post method on mailchimp api. even after changing everything it still shows const body = req.body as unexpected identifier

Comment: I made a fully functional example for you, run it and after that go to the part of requesting the mail chimp API.

Comment: Thank you I am trying to use mailchimp now.

Comment: But using mail chimp or not is not relevant with your question, rigth? Updated answer with mailchimp call

Comment: Hi how can I request a nested key value. I have updated my code in that when I console.log my postData it gives me undefined for FNAME and LNAME. How do I request it as it is in a merge field.

Comment: You are welcome! remember to accept the answer if it was helpful.